# Get the wrong value from FileTimeToSystemTime()? Why?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

```
FILETIME Kernel_Time;
HANDLE Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 0);
GetProcessTimes(Process, NULL, NULL, &Kernel_Time, NULL);
SYSTEMTIME Sys_Time;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&Kernel_Time, &Sys_Time);
printf("%d", Sys_Time.wYear); // WHY ?
```

Why `Sys_Time.wYear` is not 2013?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Hey, why are posting the same question again and again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033457/problems-in-getting-process-time-in-c-please-help-me

Comment: Even if your code *would work*: Do you really expect the System Process to be running for 2013 years? I don't think that Windows computers existed 2013 years ago...

Comment: But answer is same. ;-)

Comment: @Martin R The reason I use `Sys_Time.wYear` is to check whether this code work or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HANDLE Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 0);
```

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> If the specified process is the System Process (0x00000000), the function fails and the last error code is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

So, your `OpenProcess` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, and the `HANDLE Process` is `NULL`. Always check for the Failure conditions and respective Error Codes.

Then again, [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API parameters are not optional, so you should not be passing NULL to them instead of `pointer to FILETIME structures`.

Comment: So how to get the handle from system idle process?

Comment: What is you aim? To get the current system time year?

Comment: My aim is to get the CPU time usage of process called system idle process

Comment: @Abhineet: Your final remark probably refers to GetProcessTimes(), not OpenProcess().

Comment: @MartinR :: Thanks Martin. That was a typo (actually Copy-Paste Typo:-) )